# cannot combine left join with union

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables

table student

- name
- regid

table teacher

- name
- regid

table message

- id
- msg
- senderid
- receiverid
- ts

I want to have as result the names and regids of those who contacted a person. With the following query I can take their regids but I cannot add `left join` as I get error back all the time:

```
(SELECT sender_id AS contact FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = '...')

UNION

(SELECT receiver_id AS contact FROM messages WHERE sender_id = '...')
```

This is what I am trying to do for start:

```
SELECT teachers.name,
       teachers.regid
FROM   teachers
       LEFT JOIN ((SELECT sender_id AS contact
                   FROM   messages
                   WHERE  receiver_id = '...')
                  UNION DISTINCT
                  (SELECT receiver_id AS contact
                   FROM   messages
                   WHERE  sender_id = '...')) 
         ON t.contact = teachers.regid;
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Can you add the faulty SQL that generates this error too please?

Comment: this is what i tried: SELECT teachers.name, teachers.regid FROM teachers 
LEFT JOIN (
    (SELECT sender_id AS contact FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = '...')
    UNION DISTINCT 
    (SELECT receiver_id AS contact FROM messages WHERE sender_id = '...') 
    ) on t.contact = teachers.regid;

Comment: Give a [mre] for one piece of problem code, not 2. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please ask a new question in a new post, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing an alias for your joined inner query.
Additionally, to have a distinct union of queries, you should only use the `UNION` operator:

```
SELECT teachers.name, teachers.regid 
FROM teachers 
LEFT JOIN ( (SELECT sender_id AS contact 
             FROM   messages 
             WHERE  receiver_id = '...') 
             UNION 
            (SELECT receiver_id AS contact 
             FROM   messages 
             WHERE  sender_id = '...') ) t -- here!
ON t.contact = teachers.regid;
```

Comment: cool that solves the problem. but I also need to check that with the student table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You would add a `left join` in a `from` clause:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM ((SELECT sender_id AS contact FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = '...')
      UNION
      (SELECT receiver_id AS contact FROM messages WHERE sender_id = '...')
     ) LEFT JOIN
     blah
     ON . . . ;
```

Is this what you are doing?